# Accessing environment variables in Extended Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, extended-choice-parameter

I want to write a Groovy script for Extended Choice Parameter that would use access WORKSPACE variable. When I try:

```
List<String> artifacts = new ArrayList<String>()
artifacts.add(env.WORKSPACE)
asdf = env.WORKSPACE
println asdf
return artifacts
```

I get the following error:

```
No such property: env for class: _1775dc8d170bd01576ff2b650850017e
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: env for class: _1775dc8d170bd01576ff2b650850017e
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
at _1775dc8d170bd01576ff2b650850017e.run(_1775dc8d170bd01576ff2b650850017e:2)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
at com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.executeGroovyScript(ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java:727)
at com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.executeGroovyScriptAndProcessGroovyValue(ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java:709)
at com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.computeValue(ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java:676)
at com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.computeEffectiveValue(ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java:855)
at com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.getParameterDefinitionInfo(ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition.java:1451)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor701.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, will I be able to call a python script from this plugin, that would provide me list of parameters that I wish to use?

Comment: Does it work if you use `System.getenv("WORKSPACE")`?

Comment: Also, this question might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215394/how-to-get-environment-variable-in-jenkins-groovy-script-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env` is available in the environment of a Jenkins build. The extended choice groovy script runs before your build, as you are entering the parameters. It runs in a GroovyShell environment, and all it can do is run a simple script to render the choices for the parameter. For example, if you are creating a multi select parameter, the script to generate the choices could be:

```
return ["DEV environment", "TEST environment", "PROD environment"]
```

So you can use `env.WORKSPACE` in your Jenkinsfile or pipeline script, but in the extended choice parameter script box, it isn't defined.

According to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730186/jenkins-extended-parameter-plugin-groovy-script) answer, you should be able to use something like

```
System.getEnv().get('WORKSPACE')
```

But I couldn't get that to do what you want.

Comment: I'd need to get parameters for a Jenkins build from a web service. Is there a way to do it (different plugin, or whatever)?